# I have a object "banco" and I would like to get the property name of an object by the value of a property of this propert. (Ex:"553592729970@c.us")

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter

```
var banco = {
    "553592734057@c.us":{ // Bruno
        stage:0,
        ocupacao: '',
        nome: '',
        produto: '',
        enderecoA: '',
        enderecoB: '',
        valor: '',
    },
    "553592729970@c.us":{ // Tiago
        stage:0,
        ocupacao: 'Entregador ',
        nome: '',
        produto: '',
        enderecoA: '',
        enderecoB: '',
        valor: '',
    },
    "553599242101@c.us":{ // Juan
        stage:0,
        ocupacao: 'Entregador ',
        nome: '',
        produto: '',
        enderecoA: '',
        enderecoB: '',
        valor: '',
    }
}
```

Comment: so it could be `banco["553592729970@c.us"]`

Comment: I find question posts work better when there is an explicit question in the post body. Please see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a understand well but if i do, you can use something like that:

```
const key = Object.keys(banco).find((key) => {
    const properties = obj[key];
    // validate any property
    return properties.ocupacao = 'Entregador';
})
```

Then you will get the key **553592729970@c.us** (because it is the first occurence)